# Pros and Cons for using tsc to transpile TypeScript to JavaScript using tsc command

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, automation, protractor

I am creating a framework using `Protractor` to test `Angular` webpages. I am using `TypeScript` to create a Page Object model simply because the syntax makes more sense to me than `JavaScript`. It is more of a preference thing.

When I am running my automation scripts, I am using the command `tsc` to transpile everything from `TypeScript` to `JavaScript` because I was running into errors with my `config` file. After I run the `tsc` command, I run the `config.js` file and that runs all my `.js` files, including the Page Object files and script files. 
The issue was that `Protractor` generates global values after it reads the `config` file - so it would complain about certain syntax like `import` because that is not used in `JavaScript`.

Besides all of the extra `.js` and `.js.map` files floating in the same directory as the `.ts` files - are there any disadvantages to writing my framework using `Protractor` to test `Angular` sites using `TypeScript` and NOT using `JavaScript`? After all, when all said and done, I am using the `JavaScript` files that are generated after the `tsc` command.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. JavaScript engines don't run TypeScript, so they have to be running JS. Thus, that is what your protractor tests will be testing against. It does not matter if you manually compile with `tsc` or if you let a bundler like webpack do that for you as a preprocessor, it all compiles the same.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance - I am new to TypeScript and JavaScript. I was more concerned with what potential "issues" may occur when I use `tsc` to transcompile TypeScript to JavaScript, rather than just using JavaScript. I wasn't sure how reliable `tsc` was - if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "put it all together" yourself, rather than using a module loader, you can replace your import statements with reference comments, so instead of:

```
import * as stuff from './stuff';
```

You can use:

```
///<reference path="./stuff" />
```

And some IDEs won't even need that, as they assume all the local files will be there.

When using reference paths, you don't import or export - and you may want to deploy some namespaces to keep things out of the global scope

Having said that, of you can get a module loader involved instead - life will be even happier.

Comment: Thanks! However, I was more concerned with what potential "issues" may occur when I use `tsc` to transcompile TypeScript to JavaScript, rather than just using JavaScript.

Comment: The TypeScript compiler is rock solid, and will warn you about potential errors, so what's not to love.